# SQL get all the queries that match the request

Tags: php, sql

Hey all I am wondering how I could get ALL queries from a table, it only gets the first one and stops

My code:

```
              $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT `to` FROM transactions WHERE `from` = '$user'");

              $row = mysql_fetch_row($result1);

              $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT `amount` FROM transactions WHERE `from` = '$user'");

               $row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result2);


              echo "<li>TO</li>";
              echo "<li>AMOUNT</li>";
              echo "<li>$row[0]</li>";
              echo "<li>$row2[0]</li>";
              echo "<li>$row[1]</li>";
              echo "<li>$row2[1]</li>";
              echo "<li>$row[2]</li>";
              echo "<li>$row2[2]</li>";
              echo "<li>$row[3]</li>";
              echo "<li>$row2[4]</li>";
              echo "<li>$row[4]</li>";
              echo "<li>$row2[5]</li>";
```

My Database:

[image: I want all of the rows that say "fusion" or the to return, but it only returns first.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result1); will only fetch one row
```

You need to use `while`

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `to`, `amount` FROM transactions WHERE `from` = '$user'");
echo "<li>TO</li>";
echo "<li>AMOUNT</li>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

     echo "<li>{$row['to']}</li>";
     echo "<li>{$row['amount']}</li>";
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new to SQL could you make an example?

Comment: You should select both columns in the same query, and use `while` to loop through the results

Comment: Thank you very much, will try it now! One thing I had to do for some reason is take this `code` echo "<li>$row['to']</li>"; `code` and put it to `code` echo "<li>$row[to]</li>"; `code`